# How can I create a CustomField to choose Assets in Vaadin7 Magnolia?

Tags: vaadin, assets, custom-fields, magnolia

I'm trying to create a CustomField who allows select an asset from magnolia's assets app, with Vaadin 7, in a Magnolia Custom App. I already create a visual interface, but I cant connect with the assets app to select the asset.[visual interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x14et.png)

Answer (score 0):

You already have this kind of field in Magnolia, as described in the documentation: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Link+field

You can also use this field in your custom Magnolia app.